# Package.json parse error when trying to install express

Tags: json, node.js

Hi I am trying to install express via npm I received the following error messages:

```
npm ERR! file C:\Projects\node\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1 while parsing near 'npm 
install {
npm ERR!   "name...'
npm ERR! File: C:\Projects\node\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\george\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-
13T01_40_22_074Z-debug.log
```

I ran the package.json through a json validator and received the following:

```
 Error: Parse error on line 1:
    npm install--{  "nam
    ^
    Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got  
    undefined'
```

Here is what is inside package.json:

```
npm install --{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first project",
  main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "George Meehan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I am confused as to how to fix this.

Comment: Get rid of the `npm install --` part...

Comment: Remove `npm install --` in the `package.json`. A valid json begins with {

Comment: Thank you the instructor for the course I was following said it needed to be there. I took it out and it works fine now. I appreciate the help Andrew and Sndhar.

Answer (score 1):

The correct package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first project",
  main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "George Meehan",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```